# Powershell Out-File show only if filled

Tags: powershell, output

I'm trying to output files to a .txt, but I only want to see the attributes which are filled. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$T | ft Name,Logonworkstations | OUT-FILE c:\temp\name.txt
```

Comment: By "filled" attributes, do you mean attributes that aren't empty or null?

Comment: Well the thing i'm trying to do is extract a attribute from a bulk of accounts, but I only wanna see the accounts where this attribute is filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$T | ?{[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Name) -ne $ture -and `
       [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Logonworkstations) -ne $true} `
   | ft Name,Logonworkstations | OUT-FILE c:\temp\name.txt
```

This will check if ether `Logonworkstations` or `Name` attributes have a `$null` or and empty string (`""`) as there value. If ether of them are null/empty the line is skipped. But if both attributes has a value the object will be write to file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but when I run that I still get Name - (Null) in the .txt . What I'm trying to do is output the Name + Logonworkstations to the .txt file, but if Logonworkstations is empty I don't want them on the tekst file.

This is what is inside $T if that might help:

Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=....,OU=...., dc=...., dc=....., dc=......" -Filter * -Properties *

Comment: @ChevelloLo I have update my answer to include only users with both attributes.